# Using Regular expressions with Numeric value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgresql 9.2

What select statement would be used to find all `numeric` results that end with `.00`

Say, from this example:

```
 Trans Amt
|-------|
-57059.44
-239.00
-100.61
-181.33
-100.00
```

I would only want to see the `-100.00` and `-239.00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
`SELECT * from TABLE where TRANS_AMT = floor(TRANS_AMT);`

Answer (score 1):

May be

```
select * from Table1 where TransAmt = TransAmt::int
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/eef38/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need regular expressions?

`select n from t where n = trunc(n);`